# Spark 3.2.0 Applying a model

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, mlflow

I am using spark 3.2 to load a model to predict probability, and it doesn't seem to be working correctly, cant figure out why.

```
# Load data in spark
psdf = df.to_pandas_on_spark()
model = mlflow.sklearn.load_model('s3://bucket/r1_mlflow/')
res = model.predict_proba(psdf)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['col1' 'col2' 'col3' 'col4' 'col5']
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Does this have to do with psdf being a `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` instead of a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: can you show us how `psdf` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

sklearn doesn't understand Spark dataframes. Why not just send it the Pandas dataframe which it does understand?